# IComparable magic - why it's a valid statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't understand why it's working ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComparable.Equals(12, 3);
    }
}
```

The IL code:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       21 (0x15)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0003:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0009:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_000e:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object,
                                                        object)
  IL_0013:  pop
  IL_0014:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

It compiles to bool Object.Equals(Object,Object), but why?

Comment: Wow, that tripped me up good for a second. Note that it works with *any* (class, enum and) interface, and for any parameter type – of course (once you think about it).

Comment: Indeed works with all of the interfaces, but what's the reason behind it?

Comment: Well see David’s answer.

Comment: There is similar fun with `Encoding`: You can use `ASCIIEncoding.Unicode` to get the `UTF-16` encoding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It compiles to `bool Object.Equals(Object,Object)`, but why?

"Why?" questions are imprecise and difficult to answer, so instead I'll answer a "what?" question.

> What section of the C# specification justifies the legality of this strange behaviour?

Section 7.4 of the C# specification says that when you are doing a member lookup of the form `T.N`

> ... the set consists of all accessible members named N in T, including inherited members **and the accessible members named N in object**... [emphasis added]

`object.Equals` is an accessible member named `Equals` in `object`, so it is a candidate.

Comment: Why was it designed to be that way rather making everything have `object` as the ultimate ancestor? And it looks like I'll be needing to delete my answer.......

Comment: Curiously, PowerShell does not allow this. For example in PowerShell `[DayOfWeek]::Equals(12, 3)` works fine, but `[IDisposable]::Equals(12, 3)` complains the method does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It'd worth the time to read the C# specification at least once.

Comment: @boli: Get yourself a copy of the *annotated* C# 4 specification; it's worth a read. You can find a link to it on my blog, http://ericlippert.com.